# SystemVerilog conditional statement syntax error

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Im trying to practice SystemVerilog and attempting to implement an ALU(Arithmetic  Logic Unit) based  on this diagram:

[image]

I simulating SystemVerilog code on EDA playground online(https://www.edaplayground.com/x/mYi):

**ALU:**

```
module alu(
  input  [31:0] a,
  input  [31:0] b,
  input  [2:0] f,
  output [31:0] result,

);

  /*000*/
  if (f[0]==0 && f[1]==0 && f[2]===0)
    begin
    assign result = a & b;
    end
  /*001*/
  else (f[0]==0 && f[1]==0 && f[2]==1)
    begin
    assign result = a | b;
    end
  /*010*/
  else (f[0]==0 && f[1]==1 && f[2]==0)
    begin
    assign result = a + b;
    end
  /*011 not used*/ 
  else (f[0]==0 && f[1]==1 && f[2]==1)
    begin
    assign result = -1;
    end
  /*100*/
  else (f[0]==1 && f[1]==0 && f[2]==0)
    begin
    assign result = a & ~b;
    end 
  /*101*/  
  else (f[0]==1 && f[1]==0 && f[2]==1)  
    begin
    assign result = a | ~b;
    end
  /*110*/
  else (f[0]==1 && f[1]==1 && f[2]==0) 
    begin
    assign result = a - b;
    end
  /*111 slt*/
  else
    begin
    assign result = -1; 
    end

endmodule
```

**Partial Test Bench:**

```
module testharness();
  reg  [31:0] a;
  reg  [31:0] b;
  reg  [2:0] f;
  reg  [31:0] result;


//DUT (Device Under Test)
alu alu_0 (
  .a   (a),
  .b   (b),
  .f    (f),
  .result (result)
);

// Test program
initial begin
     /*000*/
  f[0]=0; 
  f[1]=1;
  f[2]=0;
  /*0+0*/
  a[0]=0;
  b[0]=0;

  $display( "a (%d) + b (%d) = %d%d%d%d", a[0], b[0], result[0], result[1]);
   /*000*/
  f[0]=0;
  f[1]=1;
  f[2]=0;
  /*0+1*/
  a[0]=0;
  b[0]=1;

 $display( "a (%d) + b (%d) = %d%d", a[0], b[0], result[0], result[1]);

     /*000*/
  f[0]=0;
  f[1]=1;
  f[2]=0;
  /*1+1*/
  a[0]=1; 
  b[0]=1; 

  $display( "a (%d) + b (%d) = %d%d", a[0], b[0], result[0], result[1]);

  $finish;
end

endmodule
```

**I keep getting  this error:**

ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: (. Expected tokens: '???' , ';' , 'always' , 'and' , 'assign' ... ." "design.sv" 15  9

This is line:

```
else (f[0]==0 && f[1]==0 && f[2]==1)
    begin
    assign result = a | b;
    end
```

I dont  see anything obvious.

Thanks

Comment: please start with reading a verilog tutorial. You either misused generate 'if` statements, or continuous assignments, or both.

Comment: You are missing the `if` keyword. Also instead of a long string of `if..else if..else` I would use  'case'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing up combinational logic using the `always`statement and continuous assignments. As mentioned earlier by other users, I also think it would be good if you would take a look at some basic Verilog tutorials. Asic-world.com has some great tutorials to get started with, for example, [Verilog in One Day](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog_one_day.html) by Deepak Kumar Tala.

However, let me try to explain this to you. What you are using in your example is the *continuous assignment statement*. You can find more about this in section 10.3.2 in the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://www.ece.uah.edu/~gaede/cpe526/2012%20System%20Verilog%20Language%20Reference%20Manual.pdf). The manual says:

> Assignments on nets or variables shall be continuous and automatic. In
>   other words, whenever an operand in the right-hand expression changes
>   value, the whole right-hand side shall be evaluated.

This is not the case here since the right-hand side operands of all your assignment statements are the same. It is not automatic, because it depends on your if statements. Take a look at this really simple example below. If you always want `result` to be `a & b`, you can use the code below. However, as you can imagine, for more complex logic this becomes rather lengthy.

```
module alu(
  input  [31:0] a,
  input  [31:0] b,
  output [31:0] result,

);

    assign result = (a & b);

endmodule
```

That's why SystemVerilog offers procedural blocks like `always`, `always_comb`, `always_latch`, and `always_ff` (section 9 in the IEEE Std 1800-2012). For your example, you should use `always_comb`. To quote section 9.2.2.2 of the manual:

> SystemVerilog provides a special always_comb procedure for modeling
>   combinational logic behavior.

With this, we could rewrite your code to

```
module alu(
  input  [31:0] a,
  input  [31:0] b,
  input  [2:0] f,
  output [31:0] result,

);

  reg [31:0] result_;   

  always_comb 
  begin
    /*000*/
    if (f[0]==0 && f[1]==0 && f[2]===0)
    begin
      result_ = a & b;
    end
    /*001*/
    else if (f[0]==0 && f[1]==0 && f[2]==1)
    begin
      result_ = a | b;
    end
    /*010*/
    else if (f[0]==0 && f[1]==1 && f[2]==0)
    begin
      result_ = a + b;
    end
    /*011 not used*/ 
    else if(f[0]==0 && f[1]==1 && f[2]==1)
    begin
      result_ = -1;
    end
    /*100*/
    else if (f[0]==1 && f[1]==0 && f[2]==0)
    begin
      assign result = a & ~b;
    end 
    /*101*/  
    else if (f[0]==1 && f[1]==0 && f[2]==1)  
    begin
      result_ = a | ~b;
    end
    /*110*/
    else if (f[0]==1 && f[1]==1 && f[2]==0) 
    begin
      result_ = a - b;
    end
    /*111 slt*/
    else
    begin
      result_ = -1; 
    end
  end // End of always_comb

  assign result = result_;

endmodule
```

Please mind that you can continously assign a `wire`, but you need to declare a variable as a `reg` to use it in an always block. That's the reason I am using `result_`, instead of directly assigning `result`. At the end of the code block, I continuously assign `result_` to `result`. Asic-world.com also has a tutorial on the [difference between regs and wires](http://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/wire_reg.html).

If you don't want to think about whether to use `reg` or `wire`, you could also use th new keyword `logic`.

Edit: As Oldfart pointed out, I orgininally forgot to fix your if...else statements. In your code, you always use `else` instead of `else if`. This is probably also the direct cause of the error the compiler is throwing at you.

Comment: really appreciated I will check out the tutorials you mentioned.

Comment: @The code compiles, however summation returns the wrong answer, it always return 01. `# KERNEL: a (0) + b (0) = (0),(1)
# KERNEL: a (1) + b (0) = (0),(1)
# KERNEL: a (1) + b (0) = (0),(1)`

Comment: @cyber101 I assume you assigned `f` when assigning `a` and `b`? What values did you assign? When trying to add, it should be `3'b010`. Did you try to isolate the issue by running this module in a small testbench?

Comment: i edited  the testbench it was incorrect, it should output `result` variable and not `f` variable. However the result returns x, instead of a number.

Comment: I checked your testbench on edaplayground.com. You have one syntax error in the `$display` on line 28. Furthermore, you connected `a` and `b` to your DUT, which are both 32'b values, but only assign bit 0 (`a[0] = 0` in stead of `a = 32'b0`). This leaves most bits of `a` and `b` undefined.